# Test CRUD operation in database with JUnit

Tags: java, database, testing, junit, crud

I've got a problem with testing *CRUD* operations using *JUnit*.

I have a Java application that works with a local db and I have to test the CRUD operations for an entity of this db.

How can I test CRUD operations if I can't actually use them?

For example, to test if a Create operation works, I have to verify that the new created entry actually corresponds to the input data. How can I do this if I can't access the Read operation ?

Comment: CRUD - Create,Retrieve,Update,Delete. What do you mean by  I can't actually use them?

Comment: Try using a framework such as dbunit or dbsetup

Comment: I mean that I can't say if Read operation is correct, so testing Create operation assuming Read will work is wrong.

And I can't use dbunit, it's a school thing I have to use junit

Comment: Refer : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/database-testing-crud.html

Comment: The guy in that tutorial uses read operation to test create, update and delete. What if read isn't correct? And how to test read?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say firstly: CRUD operations are so low level that testing them is a waste of time, and secondly, if you don't think you can test your Create operation for fear the Read operation doesn't work then you're being too academic about it - wouldn't a pragmatic approach be better?

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have the right answer in mind but couldn't follow it or act upon it.
The idea you have in mind is this:
You cannot use one set of operations for production code and test code. So to speak: you need two independent sets of operations where the one you use for your test code is already proven to work correctly.

[Independent Sets of Operations: Production vs Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbVib.png)

For example, when you want to test the *Create* operation of your entity, you need to test the state of the database via another channel (e.g. via *SELECT* with JDBC/SQL) which already works correctly.
Another test case could be that you wish to test the *Read* operation of your entity. Then before you call the *Read* operation of your entity you should set up the initial state of the database with *INSERT* via JDBC/SQL and then call the *Read* operation of the entity to check for the expected outcome.

These two independent sets of test methods are important because you cannot rely on them until you tested them. Using another independent set of methods that has been tested already, breaks this chicken-egg-problem.